# How to load WebAssembly in iOS app via WKWebVIew or JSC

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, webassembly, javascriptcore

I'm trying to load and execute a WebAssembly `.wasm` from within a Swift-based, iOS  app. I first attempted to use the [JavaScriptCore Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/javascriptcore) but the `WebAssembly.*` module wasn't available in the Context when I tried to evaluate a trivial script. I was able to confirm the `WebAssembly` isn't defined via the Safari Debugger Console.

I then attempted to use WKWebView because I'm led to believe that the lack of `WebAssembly` is due to [JSC not supporting](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2019/01/03/javascriptcore-10-months-later/) JIT, which WKWebView should. I got the same result.

Here's a trivial app running on an iPhone X 12.4 emulator, Xcode 10.3 and the WebKit Framework manually added to the project. Make sure to open Safari and Select "Developer>Simulator" for WKWebView debugger.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    @IBAction func onClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let testWasm = """
            if(typeof WebAssembly !== 'undefined') {
                console.log("Hello, Wasm.");
            } else {
                console.log("No Wasm for you!");
            }
        """

        webView.evaluateJavaScript(testWasm)
    }
}
```

Does iOS actually have a way to load WebAssembly into a Swift-based app?

Comment: I think it is due to this bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=191064

I've only been testing in the simulator!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted to run some benchmarks with JSC to compare it with Wasm3.
Basically I run into the same situation and wasn't able to fix so far.

Wasm3 [runs perfectly fine on iOS](https://github.com/wasm3/wasm3/tree/master/platforms/ios), and may suite your needs at the moment.

Currently you can't run WebAssembly with JSC on the simulator [according to this comment](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=194257#c71).

Answer (score 3):

It appears that [JavaScriptCore now has a WebAssembly interpreter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1v4wPoMskfo), as of Feb 2020.